# image_tag to only the first loop for each iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a single `image_tag` to only the first loop in each iteration.

For example, I'm trying display 3 images. This is my current code:

```
<% @album.each do |album|%>
  <% @image.each do |image| %>
    <% if album.id == image.album_id %>
      <a href="image.jpg"> <%= image_tag image_path %> </a>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I loop through `@image` with 3 images I will get this output:

```
<a href="image1.jpg"><img src="image_thumb.jpg"/></a>
<a href="image2.jpg"><img src="image_thumb.jpg"/></a>
<a href="image3.jpg"><img src="image_thumb.jpg"/></a>
```

What I want is:

```
<a href="image1.jpg"><img src="image_thumb.jpg"/></a>
<a href="image2.jpg"></a>
<a href="image3.jpg"></a>
```

What this does is the first image thumb will serve as the cover page for the album. When you click on the link, it will display a lightbox gallery that loops through all the images for that album.

I can get this result with css a:nth-child and display: none. But display: none will still download all the thumbnail images even though they aren't displaying anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Album and Image models are associated with following relation:

```
class Album
  has_many :images
end

class Image
  belongs_to :album
end
```

Then you can use following for better performance:

```
<% @album.each do |album|%>
  <% album.images.each_with_index do |image, i| %>
    <a href="image.jpg"> <%= image_tag image_path if i==0 %> </a>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks this works and answers the other question I asked below :) Thank you very much.